# How to configure ejabberd rest api?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, ejabberd-api

Can some please explain me how to configure ejabberd rest api support, I could not find any sufficient resource regarding this.

I'm using linux (kubuntu 16.04), so till now I've done 
`sudo apt-get install ejabberd`
and please tell me is there any need of `/etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.cfg` or all the config is done in `/etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.yml` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All configuration is done in `ejabberd.yml`. The documentation for oauth and ReST API is here: [ejabberd OAuth Support](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/oauth/)

Comment: Can you please tell me the exact configuration required to be done in ejabberd.yml file to use mod_rest

Comment: mod_rest is a contribution but we do not use it as ejabberd now includes ReST API using OAuth. The link I provided is now the reference for ejabberd official module.

Comment: Will it work in ejabberd version 16.01, as I'm using version 16.01

Comment: well, I tried as given in the doc, but when I entered the user, server and password at https://localhost:5280/oauth/authorization_token?response_type=token&client_id=Client1&redirect_uri=https://localhost:5280&scope=get_roster+sasl_auth url, I received no token

Comment: Instead I received following error 2016-07-20 17:06:01.285 [error] <0.1021.0> CRASH REPORT Process <0.1021.0> with 0 neighbours crashed with reason: call to undefined function oauth2:authorize_password({<<"ankit">>,<<"localhost">>}, <<"Client1">>, <<"https://localhost:5280">>, [<<"get_roster">>,<<"sasl_auth">>], {password,<<"12345">>})

Comment: Probably wrongly installed. You are missing modules.

Comment: ok I reinstalled ejabberd, now I'm using version 16.06, also I'm able to get the token but when I use that token using command `curl -X GET -H "X-Admin: true" -H "Authorization: Bearer dr78JYZBTE570D99kSSL7A8Fn13xgAIE" http://localhost:5280/api/connected_users`, I get `"401 Unauthorized"`

Comment: Hi. I also get the same error when using the token. How did you solve the error?